# Django remember me doesn't work

Tags: django

I want, to close session when browser is closed, but if user checked remember me, session must be open after browser close, so i did this one but it doesn't work, it always closes.

my settings.py:

```
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
```

my views.py

```
if request.POST['rememberme']:
        settings.SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = False
```

Comment: That can't possibly work. Settings are global to a project.

Comment: what can i do??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

def login_user(request, template_name='registration/login.html', extra_context=None):  
    response = auth_views.login(request, template_name)  
    if request.POST.has_key('remember_me'):    
        request.session.set_expiry(1209600) # 2 weeks
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', login_user, name='auth_login'),
]
```